# How can we call dataframe functions like (mean, median, mode, min ...) dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

fields = {'rule1':'min','rule2':'max'}

For example:

```
for key, value in fields.items():
    Dataframe.{value}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try getattr as below**

```
fields = {
    'mean': df.mean,
    'median': df.median,
    'mode': df.mode,
    'min': df.min,
    'max': df.max
}

for key, value in fields.items():
        # Call the method using getattr()
        result = getattr(df, value)()
        print(f'The result of calling {key}() is: {result}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1]])
for f in ('min', 'max'):
  print(getattr(df, f)())
```